# regex pattern for alpha numeric value

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex pattern allowing only alphanumeric value, neither only alphabets nor digits, having minimum length = 4 and maximum length = 15,

I tried using `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,15}$/` , but this pattern also allows only alphabets and only digits.

Please help me out

Comment: The regex pattern you mention should allow alphabets OR digits.

Comment: @SiddharthaRT that's the problem he only want to get mixed results

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

`^(?=^.{4,15}$)([a-zA-Z]+[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$`

See working example here: http://regexr.com?351ia

**Explanation:** (Updated: now with length check)

First the positive lookahead `(?=^.{4,15}$)` checks the length of your string.

If your string starts with a letter this part of the regex is used to evaluate it:

`[a-zA-Z]+[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*`

- `[a-zA-Z]+` means that the string starts with at least one letter
- `[0-9]` then at some point there must be a number
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` followed by any amount of numbers or letters

If your string starts with a number the second part of the regex is used:

`[0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Same as the above, only this time there *must* be a letter somewhere in the string.

Comment: You did not check for the length constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do a double lookahead to look for numbers and letters, once numbers and letters are found, the match will continue, else it won't.

Regex: `/^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,15}$/`

Answer (score 0):

Use your original for the alphanumeric and length tests, then verify that the string contains alpha **and** numeric by testing for a digit followed by an alpha or vice-versa anywhere in the string.

```
   /^[a-z\d]{4,15}$/i.test (s) && /\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d/i.test (s);
```